# Reading \" inside "..." as string token

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using C# regular expressions for my project in compiler design.

I'm working with a lexical analyzer and I have to tokenize the code depending on the rules I have set.

I defined my string as `[\".*?\"]`  and double quote as `[\"]`.

When I input `"Hi"` it is read as STRING TOKEN.

**But** when I input `" \" "`, it yields STRING for `" \"` and DOUBLE-QUOTE for `"`.

I want it to be read as STRING TOKEN.

In other words, I want to correctly parse strings containing escaped double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the pattern you want is:

```
"(?:[^"]|\")*"
```

This will match any non-quote character or slash-quote pair inside quotes. For example:

```
var input = @"1 2 3 ""Hello \""Word\""!""";
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"""(?:[^""]|\"")*""");

Console.WriteLine(match.Value); // "Hello \"Word\"!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try printing out the ASCII codes for each character you input. The backslashes will have different effects depending on whether your input is on a command line, via a GUI, or from a file.

Your reluctant matcher may be treating the `\` as a character in its own right and not a modifier for the `"`.